# Is it possible to create an infinite-dimensional JavaScript array?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create (or simulate) an infinite-dimensional array in JavaScript. Essentially, this would be an data structure that would associate objects with lists of integers (which could be of any length). Is there an efficient way to store each element in this data structure?

```
function addElement(theObject, coordinates){
    //object is the object, and coordinates is the list of coordinates (any number of coordinates will be accepted, since it's infinite-dimensional)
}

function getObject(coordinates){
    //get the object that was previously assigned to this list of coordinates
}
addElement("Hello World", [0, 0, 3, 5]);
console.log(getObject([0, 0, 3, 5])); //this would print "Hello World".
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: what do you mean infinite-dimentional? javascript arrays don't have a limit to it's length so it's already "infinite" if that's what you mean.

Comment: @WaleedKhan I'm trying to implement a quadtree in JavaScript, where elements can be added or removed from the quadtree by listing the coordinates, along with the object to add to the quadtree.

Comment: @kennypu Yeah, but arrays are one-dimensional.

Comment: I think you want to look into a hashing method. You could hash the coordinates and get the object.

Comment: @WaleedKhan yes, but a multi-dimentional array is merely an array within an array. There is no restriction on the depth of the array.

Comment: @WaleedKhan Hm, that might be useful. I could try using some kind of hashing method.

Comment: Lazy evaluation could also lead to the appearance of an infinite dimension array, but I don't think that's what you want here.

Comment: Do you need to enumerate the contents in some meaningful way? Or simply store the values and return them based on exact key match?

Comment: @ErikE I just want to associate each object with a set of integer coordinates. Would that make it possible to enumerate the contents in some meaningful way?

Comment: You are creating a (very) sparse logical array. Do you need to be able to do things like step through the parts in some ordered way? Let's say you store values for `[0,0,3,5]` and `[0,99999,2,4]`. Do you need to loop from `0 to 0` in the first level, then `0 to 99999` in the second for first-level value `0`, then so on?

Comment: @ErikE Most likely I will. It might be useful to obtain a 2D array from the data set, if I'm going to use it to represent a quadtree.

Comment: Then that affects how you implement it. How you wish to traverse the space will probably change things. One possibility is that you could use an array after all instead of an object, and sort it, though sorting will be a challenge because you'll have to be able to find the index from the value (or store the index in the value).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless there is any reason you can't, I would just use the coordinate as an index, and store things there:

```
var coordinates = [];
var testCoord = [0,0,3,5];
coordinates[testCoord] = "Hello World";
console.log(coordinates[testCoord]);
```

Comment: You Should make it explicit that you are converting the coordinates `[0, 0, 3, 5]` to the string `'0,0,3,5'`.

Comment: Also, you should probably use `coordinates = {}` instead of `[]` because it's not really an array...

Comment: This is a simple and concise solution, but I'd like to know how it compares to the other solution (in terms of memory usage).

Comment: This is going to have the lowest memory usage of all: a single-level object, with one member per stored "coordinate".

Comment: @ErikE yeah, initially I had a. toString() on the coordinate, but I figured it does that anyways and this way is much neater

Comment: @kennypu It's not neater because code should be written for humans, not for computers. Having secret conversions going on is, in my opinion, not best practice and can lead to bugs and misunderstanding by other people who will (one day, if your code has any quality and your company lasts) be maintained by someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. Just loop:

```
(function() {
  var store = [];
  window.addElement = function(theObject,coordinates) {
    var t = store, l = coordinates.length, i;
    for(i=0; i<l-1; i++) {
      if( typeof t[coordinates[i]] !== "undefined" && !(t[coordinates[i]] instanceof Array))
        (function(old) {(t[coordinates[i]] = []).toString = function() {return old;};})(t[coordinates[i]]);
      t = t[coordinates[i]] = t[coordinates[i]] || [];
    }
    t[coordinates[i]] = theObject;
  }
  window.getObject = function(coordinates) {
    var t = store, l = coordinates.length, i;
    for(i=0; i<l-1; i++) {
      t = t[coordinates[i]];
      if( !(t instanceof Array)) throw new Error("Invalid coordinate");
    }
    return t[coordinates[i]];
  }
})();

addElement("Hello World",[0,0,3,5]);
console.log(getObject([0,0,3,5]));
```

Comment: But... why not return the `getObject` and `addElement` in an object from the IIFE?

Comment: @WaleedKhan I'm not sure what you mean. The functions are being added to the `window` object.

Comment: Why add them to `window`? Why not add them to an object and then return that object?

Comment: @WaleedKhan Because the original question had them defined as functions in the global scope, so I kept to the same pattern. The code could easily be adapted into a class-like structure, but that wasn't how the question was asked.

Comment: I've found a bug in the implementation: http://jsfiddle.net/GwgDN/ It should print "Hello World", but instead it throws an error. Using nested arrays seems to overwrite the original value in this case.

Comment: @AndersonGreen Added code to fix that. Now if an element is already there, it is replaced with an array whose string value is set to be the existing value.